# Main AC drain Clogged

Tags: hvac, drain

Main drain is clogged since secondary line is in use.   Is this my main drain line?   It goes into the ground and my guess it’s connected to an underground French drain.

[image]

Comment: Is your only question whether this is your condensate line? That doesn't seem like a question for the internet. What's it connected to inside? Did you dig around at all?

Comment: I'd be concerned about the water-tight conduit pulling out of the wall. By definition, the inside of conduit is wet, so water ingress into the conduit isn't a problem. _However_, you now have an _easy_ way for water to get into your house, _and_ you have wire insulation rubbing against the rough edge of the brick and not protected by the conduit.

Comment: I would make sure that drain is going to another drain pipe or cut it above the ground.  Gravity drains on an ac system can be plugged by spider webs , really the water tension alone with spider webs can plug things and then some gunkies and it gets really nasty, dig down and see if it is blocked or another pipe, if another pipe get some biocides tablets and flush some water down a computer keyboard “duster” works well to get things flowing nozzle in the drain a rag to plug the hole and pull the trigger it usually starts flowing, keep adding biocide tablets as needed my area a 10-15$ bag lasts